# Python: fail to swap two elements in a list

Tags: python

Is there anyone can help me to have a look at this code.
I am trying to solve the first missing positive question in leetcode.
But this code cause an endless loop as I found I fail to swap the A[i] and A[A[i]-1]. But I have test to swap to elements in list using this simple code:

```
A = [2,1]
A[0], A[1] = A[1], A[0]
print A # A = [1,2]
```

I do not know what the mistake is :(

```
def firstMissingPositive(self, A):
    i = 0
    length = len(A)
    while i < length:
        if A[i] >= 1 and A[i] <= length:
            if A[i] != i+1 and A[A[i]-1] != A[i]:
                A[i], A[A[i]-1] = A[A[i]-1], A[i]
            else:
                i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    for i in range(length):
        if A[i] != i+1:
            return i+1
    return length + 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're modifying `A[i]` during the execution of the assignment statement, and so the evaluation of `A[A[i]-1]` on the left-hand side of the `=` won't evaluate the way you're expecting it to.  You need to change this:

```
A[i], A[A[i]-1] = A[A[i]-1], A[i]
```

to this:

```
tmp = A[i]-1
A[i], A[tmp] = A[tmp], A[i]
```

This phenomenon is addressed by a note in the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> WARNING: Although the definition of assignment implies that overlaps between the left-hand side and the right-hand side are 'safe' (for example `a, b = b, a` swaps two variables), overlaps *within* the collection of assigned-to variables are not safe! For instance, the following program prints `[0, 2]`:
>
> ```
> x = [0, 1]
> i = 0
> i, x[i] = 1, 2
> print x
> ```

Comment: Thanks you so much!! :) That's the mistake!~